# Which is the best mobile platform to develop a blockchain based mobile application

Tags: blockchain, android

I am new to the blockchain technology. For my semester porject i have to debelop a blockchain based healthdata management system. That includes a blockchain developed using ethereum to store the data and a mobile application to access the blockchain and update and view data. I want to know what i the best platform to develop mobile application (react native or androdi(java/kotlin)). I am good in android.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what is the "best platform", but:

If you're comfortable with Android, it would be worth looking at MetaMask mobile: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile

If I were doing it, since I am most comfortable with .NET I'd be looking at samples like this: https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.UI.Wallet.Sample